# After creating another account it's showing failed "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again."

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

i've created a login authentication form, when first time user makes their account it's showing "successfully created, and everything goes well ok but when i create other account using other email and username it's showing this error message `Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.` what's that meaning ? please help

code for Creating table:

```
// Create table
$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each user, unique index',
  `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name, unique',
  `user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
  `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email, unique',
  `college` varchar(105) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s college, unique',
  `branch` varchar(105) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s branch, unique',
  `course_year` varchar(105) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s course_year, unique',
  `name` varchar(105) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name, unique',
  `hometown` varchar(105) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s hometown, unique',
  `gender` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s gender, unique',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `college` (`college`),
  UNIQUE KEY `branch` (`branch`),
  UNIQUE KEY `course_year` (`course_year`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hometown` (`hometown`),
  UNIQUE KEY `gender` (`gender`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data'";
```

everything goes well but after creating another account it's showing that error message..

here is code for `Registration.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class registration
 * handles the user registration
 */
class Registration
{
    /**
     * @var object $db_connection The database connection
     */
    private $db_connection = null;
    /**
     * @var array $errors Collection of error messages
     */
    public $errors = array();
    /**
     * @var array $messages Collection of success / neutral messages
     */
    public $messages = array();

    /**
     * the function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
     * you know, when you do "$registration = new Registration();"
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
            $this->registerNewUser();
        }
    }

    /**
     * handles the entire registration process. checks all error possibilities
     * and creates a new user in the database if everything is fine
     */
    private function registerNewUser()
    {
        if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Empty Username";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password_new']) || empty($_POST['user_password_repeat'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Empty Password";
        } elseif ($_POST['user_password_new'] !== $_POST['user_password_repeat']) {
            $this->errors[] = "Password and password repeat are not the same";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_password_new']) < 6) {
            $this->errors[] = "Password has a minimum length of 6 characters";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_name']) > 64 || strlen($_POST['user_name']) < 2) {
            $this->errors[] = "Username cannot be shorter than 2 or longer than 64 characters";
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $_POST['user_name'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Username does not fit the name scheme: only a-Z and numbers are allowed, 2 to 64 characters";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_email'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Email cannot be empty";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_email']) > 64) {
            $this->errors[] = "Email cannot be longer than 64 characters";
        } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['user_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->errors[] = "Your email address is not in a valid email format";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['college']) || empty($_POST['branch']) || empty($_POST['course_year'])){
            $this->errors[]="Select your college, branch, and year.";
        } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name'])
            && strlen($_POST['user_name']) <= 64
            && strlen($_POST['user_name']) >= 2
            && preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $_POST['user_name'])
            && !empty($_POST['user_email'])
            && strlen($_POST['user_email']) <= 64
            && filter_var($_POST['user_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
            && !empty($_POST['user_password_new'])
            && !empty($_POST['user_password_repeat'])
            && ($_POST['user_password_new'] === $_POST['user_password_repeat'])
        ) {
            // create a database connection
            $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            // change character set to utf8 and check it
            if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
                $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
            }

            // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
            if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

                // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
                $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['user_name'], ENT_QUOTES));
                $user_email = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['user_email'], ENT_QUOTES));

                $user_password = $_POST['user_password_new'];

                // crypt the user's password with PHP 5.5's password_hash() function, results in a 60 character
                // hash string. the PASSWORD_DEFAULT constant is defined by the PHP 5.5, or if you are using
                // PHP 5.3/5.4, by the password hashing compatibility library
                $user_password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $college=$_POST['college'];
                $branch=$_POST['branch'];
                $course_year=$_POST['course_year'];
                $name=$_POST['name'];
                $hometown=$_POST['hometown'];
                $gender=$_POST['sex'];

                // check if user or email address already exists
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_email . "';";
                $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

                if ($query_check_user_name->num_rows == 1) {
                    $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that username / email address is already taken.";
                } else {
                    // write new user's data into database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, college, branch, course_year, name, hometown, gender)
                            VALUES('" . $user_name . "', '" . $user_password_hash . "', '" . $user_email . "', '".$college."', '".$branch."', '".$course_year."', '".$name."', '".$hometown."', '".$gender."');";
                    $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

                    // if user has been added successfully
                    if ($query_new_user_insert) {
                        $this->messages[] = "Your account has been created successfully. You can now log in.";
                    } else {
                        $this->errors[] = "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Sorry, no database connection.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "An unknown error occurred.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table definition seem to be the problem, you are using a unique key constraint for almost every column, meaning inserts will fail if you have a dublicate value in any column. Even the gender column has a unique constraint. So you can only have 2 entries in your table(one man and one woman).

You can get the exact error description by checking the return of mysql_error() after the failing insert.

Comment: I wish to vote you up to +122220000000000 but unfortunately i've less scored i'm extremly sorry for that but you awsome mann...... thanks again thanks thanks ;)